# Cells become #REF errors when using VBA to copy sheets into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, export

I am trying to automate exporting a report I produce every week. Basically, it aggregates data from a bunch of other sheets using VLOOKUP and INDIRECT. I want to copy out the summary sheet into a new workbook as a values-only sheet.

The code that I thought would work is below:

```
Sub ExportSSHMIL()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    
        Sheets(Array("SSH New Starts by Site by Week", "MIL New Starts by Site by Week")).Select
        Sheets(Array("SSH New Starts by Site by Week", "MIL New Starts by Site by Week")).Copy
        
        Sheets("SSH New Starts by Site by Week").Activate
            Cells.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

However,  when the above code it run, the sheets are "successfully" copied, but all of the cells which used the aforementioned VLOOKUP and INDIRECT are now #REF values.

How can I successfully copy these sheets into a new workbook as values only?

Thank you for any help/advice you can give me!!

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that the sheets also include charts and column groups that would ideally also be copied over.

**Edit:** [image: Example of Column Groupings]

Comment: 1. No need to select anything. 2. You need to specify the sheet where the values to be pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' Sheets("SSH New Starts by Site by Week")
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   If Not Application.CopyObjectsWithCells Then _
          Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
   sh.Copy 'it creates a new workbook containing the copy of the sheet...
   With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        sh.UsedRange.Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi FaneDuru! Thank you for this! This works great except it does not copy over any of the charts or column groupings I also have. Is there a way to modify the above code to replicate these?

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS Of course, not. This is what `xlPasteValues` does. You did not mention anything about any chart. You only said that your problem consist in impossibility of copying the values... Is is something else, except the charts which should be copied?

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention it and edited my post accordingly. Sorry about that! Ideally, it would copy over the charts which graph the data on the sheet and the column groupings.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, Thank you for all of your help! I added a screenshot of the sheet including the column groupings at the top. I am not sure how else to descript them, but they are those grey squares with the "+" or "-" in them which can be expanded or contracted to show/hide certain columns.

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS Please, test the updated code. It copies all the sheet and then the values and format...

Comment: Your updated code successfully copies over the column groupings, but not the chart.

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS This should not be possible. I tested the code, with a chart and another shape and it copies everything. It copies everything and then copy the values and formats. Can you share the workbook you use?

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS -  Make sure you have `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True`    It's not always turned on.

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes, you are right. The `True` is the default value but looking to his code, it starts with `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False`. Not payed enough attention to his code... Adapted the answer to do the correct thing, from this point of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with copying formulas using `INDIRECT` - these won't transpose without getting that `#REF` error. You'll need to copy/paste the values first, create the new workbook, then close your old workbook without saving. Something like:

```
Sub ExportSSHMIL()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
    
    Dim currwb As Workbook
    
    Set currwb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Sheets("SSH New Starts by Site by Week").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("SSH New Starts by Site by Week").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Sheets(Array("SSH New Starts by Site by Week", "MIL New Starts by Site by Week")).Copy
    
    currwb.Close False
    
End Sub
```